# How to show split view spotlight results without clicking

Tags: macos, big-sur

I just upgraded to Big Sur.

Something I don't like is that Spotlight doesn't show BIG RESULTS for dictionary definitions and calculator, unless you click on them.

It used to be that the answer to the calculation was automatically displayed largely in a panel on the right half of the results.

Similarly for the dictionary, in fact Spotlight now doesn't show me the word's pronunciation, etymology, alternative definitions, etc, unless I click on the result physically with my mouse (maybe there is also a hidden keyboard shortcut for it)

How can I make it present the results as it used to in Catalina, without me having to do any additional action other than search?

Answer (score 1):

Spotlight has changed quite disruptively for many workflows and I am not sure that in right direction. There is a choice: adapt or resist the change. Following is from adaption perspective:

How to display calculation results largely in a panel on the right half of the results > press <kbd>⇥</kbd> (TAB) at the end of calculation.

For dictionary > use <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd> to navigate to `Definition` block and press enter (or alternatively enter term, then <kbd>⇥</kbd> (TAB) which displays preview and then navigate to Definition block; during navigation preview stays open)

If you are looking for "word's pronunciation, etymology, alternative definitions, etc" then one option it to search directly within Dictionary app (or use `dict://` at the beginning in Spotlight and then press Enter which takes to Dictionary term)